# How can I change my profile picture on Octopus?

Tags: octopus-deploy

Is there a way to change my profile picture on Octopus without creating an account on Gravatar.com? Can I upload a picture from my computer?

If not, why is it not possible?

[image: Octopus picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is [not supported yet](https://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/17101-change-user-picture-no-access-to-the-internet).

There is a very [similar user voice from 2013](https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/forums/170787-general/suggestions/3855047-add-a-system-wide-setting-to-turn-off-gravatar-m) if you'd like to promote one.